# Symfony 2 - at the welcome page images and styles are loaded but not rendered

Tags: symfony

I have this weird issue with Symfony 2, right after installation on my VPS. The welcome page is loaded properly except... that some images and some styles are loaded, but not rendered. Can You please help me with solving this mistery?

[image]

Hints:
* During the installation, I had a problem with 'data-time zone' - I don't know is that has anything to do with it but... may be it'll be a clue...

Thanx in advance for any advice!

**UPDATE:**
Things that are not loading properly throws the following messages under the console
[image]

Comment: Maybe a issue with your webserver.

Comment: I took that in mind, but on the other hand, wouldn't all images and styles be broken than ?

Comment: Pazi - U were right! Thanx for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it appeared that it's truly the Apache's installation fault.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? What setting/config of Apache caused the problem and how did you fix it?

Comment: I'm no longer on PHP and berly remember this thread, sorry. I'm on NodeJS these days.